# How to sort an array in PHP while it retrieve using forloop

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my actual requirement (edited)

```
array('1-One','2-second','10-ten','3-third','11-elevan','4-four')
```

How can I print the above array as

```
1-One
2-second
3-third
4-four
10-ten
11-elevan
```

ie by the sort order of prefix number

Comment: Could you please post an example of your array and your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort($array,SORT_NUMERIC);//add extra parameter to change default sorting behave
print_r($array);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/pinj8dJJ)

Comment: `natsort($array)` would be more appropriate as the content is mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sort](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.sort.php) before you print your array.

```
$array = array(1,10,2,12,3);
sort($array);
print_r($array);
```